# Detect device orientation in flame (flutter package)

Tags: flutter, flame

I've been following the doodle dash tutorial for flame in flutter:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-flame-game#0 
I'd like to modify it so that the user can tip the phone left and right to move dash, rather than having on-screen buttons.  However, I can't find anything in the docs which refers to an `OrientationDetector` or anything like it.  Is there something here that I'm missing, or is this missing from flame?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flame does not provide this from within the engine, to act upon such events you should use an external package like for example [sensors_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus) or any of the other packages that provide you with gyroscope data.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem like a bit of a gap, given that there's so many other detectors within flame.

Comment: The other detectors come from flutter, flutter doesn't expose the sensors directly.
We could make a bridge package, but it wouldn't do much more than the user's package of choice from pub.dev.